# Grave (backtick) key for the keyboard shortcut is not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Gnome desktop supports `<Alt>Grave` as far as I know:

https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/gnome3-extra/keybindings.conf

and when I press `Alt + backtick` button at the `settings > keyboard > shortcuts`
It shows up a corresponding symbols. But it doesn't actually work. Is this a bug? There doesn't seem to be any other application interfering with it.

I am desperate for this key binding because of my muscle memory. Any other workaround will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

ibus had a binding that needed to be changed to avoid the conflict. You can check this by doing either:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i grave
```

by default gnome desktop has a binding, but with a different name `<Alt>Above_Tab`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-groups "[]"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group-backward "[]"
```